# Probability - Removing a ball and replacing with the same colour.

Tags: probability

Question:
A box contains g green balls and v violet balls.
A ball is drawn at random. 
It's colour is recorded and is returned to the box with another ball of the same colour. 
The process is repeated indefinitely.

1. What is the probability the second ball taken out the box is violet?
2. What is the probability the first ball is violet given that the
   second ball is violet?

My attempt, though I feel like I am going down the entirely wrong path as . I probably should be working with permutations:

R = V B = G

[image]

Would anyone be able to provide a explained solution as I am quite confused by this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question, there are two alternatives:
First ball is green, second is violet.
First ball is violet, second is violet.
$\frac{g}{v+g} \cdot\frac{v}{g+v+1} + \frac{v}{v+g} \cdot\frac{v+1}{g+v+1}$
For the second question use Bayes' theorem.

So you need basicaly three values. One you have from previous point ( $P(second=v)$). 
 The other are 
 $P(first=v)=\frac{v}{g+v}$ 
$P(second=v|first=v) = \frac{v+1}{v+g+1}$
Now we are done: $P(first=v|second=v) = \frac{P(s=v|f=v)\cdot P(f=v)}{P(s=v)} = \frac{v+1}{g+v+1}$

Comment: Hi DDT, could you please show me the working out for the second part using Baye theorem

Comment: I've edited my answer, but you really should repeat Bayes' theorem by yourself. It's core of that kind of problems.

Answer (score 0):

1) you could pull Green Violet, or you could pull violet violet.

$P(GV) = \frac {g}{g+v}\cdot \frac {v}{g+v+1}\\
P(VV) = \frac {v}{g+v}\cdot \frac {v+1}{g+v+1}\\
P(GV) + P(VV) = \frac {gv+v^2 + v}{(g+v)(g+v+1)}$

2) what is the problability that the first pull was violet based on the information that the second pull was violet.

$\frac {P(VV)}{P(GV)+P(VV)} = \frac {v^2 + v}{gv+v^2 + v}$

Comment: Shouldn't the second part have P(VV) and P(VG) as the numerator to represent all the ways to get a violet first? If not, why?

Comment: Could you please show me the working

Comment: I don't have any more work to show.... regarding 2) the probability that the first ball was violet ... It is the number of ways that the for the proposition to be true / the number of ways that the condition is true.